# Gesture overlay view do not recognizing DOT in Android

Tags: android, gesture

While using Gesture Overlay view in android DOT not recognized.

Is there any solution to do this by using Gesture Overlay or I need to choose any other classes.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks